# Given a point and direction, how to get a new point which is 1 unit away on left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Given we have:

- Vector3 point `a` in a space
- Vector3 direction of point `a` (normalized)

How to get a new Vector3 (`b`) which is 1 unit away on left (or right) of point `a`?

```
Vector3 a = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0.9417419, 0, 0.3363364);
```

Comment: I remember seeing an answer to this in Unity forums but I just can't find it anymore.

Comment: You also need an `up` direction. Then a point to the right of a would be `r = a + Vector3.Cross(direction, up).normalized`

Comment: @Pluto Unity uses left-hand systems, so that would be on the left of point `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pluto says, you can use a cross product to find that, if you have an up direction. However, Unity uses left-handed systems, so (direction X up) would be on the left side. You can use the negative of `direction` to find the right side. For instance:

```
Vector3 a = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0.9417419, 0, 0.3363364);    
Vector3 localUp = Vector3.up;

bool onLeft = true;

Vector3 b = Vector3.Cross(onLeft ? direction : -direction, localUp).normalized + a;
```